# use 3rd library with android pure ndk

Tags: android-ndk

I know how to link with a shared library, and I know if launched by java code, we can System.loadLibrary every .so. So, my question is: how to load multiple .so files with pure ndk. The value of "meta-data android:name='android.app.lib_name'" in AndroidManifest.xml only can specials one library name, how to add the other shared librarys name?

Comment: Use the Android.mk file to specify dependancies on other libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems Im not understanding, because if load shared library from java, we need load each shared librarys by System.loadLibrary. but from pure ndk, you can only have one entry, other shared librarys must explicit linked the entry library. so, the android system will load them automaticly.